# Adjust time monthly time axis in ggplot2 to quarters?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got folowing data frame:

```
          MONTH MINTEREST REGION    id
 <S3: yearmon>     <dbl>  <chr> <int>
1      Aug 2010    0.0443     NC     1
2      Sep 2010    0.0432     NC     2
3      Okt 2010    0.0422     NC     3
4      Nov 2010    0.0433     NC     4
5      Dez 2010    0.0475     NC     5
6      Jan 2011    0.0480     NC     6
```

I use following ggplot2 code to plot the frame:

```
ggplot(MINTEREST30, aes(x=MONTH, y=MINTEREST, group=REGION)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=REGION),size=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#86BC25","#0076A8","#BBBCBC","#E3E48D","#A0DCFF"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  xlab("Months")+
  ylab("Mortgage Rate")
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type yearmon.
>   Defaulting to continuous.

[image]

And also as you can see in the graphic which is provided above, ggplot sets the x-axis automatically to year. Due to that I dont have any starting point, since my data starts in August 2010.

My question is: Is it somehow possible to adjust the axis to quarters or even months?

Comment: Have a look of [this link](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html). I think this is one way to start looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `p` is the value of the `ggplot` statement in the question then try one of these:

```
p + scale_x_yearmon(format = "'%y/%m", n = 10)

p + scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%yQ%q", n = 10)
```

Modify or even leave out the format and n depending on what looks nice.  With the data shown in the question the above choices seemed ok.  Likely any sufficiently large number would be ok for n.  For more info see `?scale_x_yearmon`.

Answer (score 0):

jazzurro has put you on the right path. Id try something like :

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b-%y")
```